# How to retrieve data from a child node in Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I already have a onDataChange written to get values from a different child node,but what I need is to change the key to let's say "new" and then retrieve the data from that child

Any inputs would be appreciated ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand, you want to change a field and bring back the changed data.

[image]

for e.g, for this data structure, if you want the change `Username`, create a User modal with different name, `User newUser = new User("https://...","newUserName)`. And change the field in User modal

```
public String Profile;
public String newKey;
```

Then give the new modal to that uid,

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("ECWHIksxJ0Q5SUIIrev4BjnjmrJ3").setValue(newUser, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                        DatabaseReference yourRef = databaseReference.getRef();
                    }
                });
```

Now you have the changed data's reference. Did you try something like this?

**Update:**

If you want to update multiple value/field with single action, you should create a map and put every path into it with values.

In firebase, every table, every specific field is an path. Consider the data structure shown above. If you want change `Username` field:

```
HashMap<String, Object> updateMap = new HashMap<>();

updateMap.put("/Users/ECWHIksxJ0Q5SUIIrev4BjnjmrJ3/Username", "newUserName");
```

For different user:

```
updateMap.put("/Users/DIFFERENT_USER_KEY/Username", "newUserName2");
```

For diffrent table:

```
updateMap.put("/YourOtherTable/DifferentPath/DifferentField", true);
```

Then get your database root reference and update all at once.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().updateChildren(updateMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener...)
```

This is very simple way to update a lot of things in one action, but it's causing problems when writing `firebase rules`. Because you get your root reference and try to set a value to it. The choice is yours.

Comment: Ah yes..Thanks a lot this helped.

Comment: @AtaerCaner What if i want to change data for alot of users? How can i do that without hard coding the random key?